# Usage of 上で in this sentence

Tags: grammar, nuances, sentence

There is a question in the Kanzen Master N2 Textbook:

> この薬は、_____上でお飲みください
>
> a. 食事が終わった
>
> b. 医師が説明した
>
> c. 説明書をよく読んだ

According to the answer sheet, the answer is c.

But I don't understand why a. and b. are wrong.

From what I understand of 上で in this context

```
A上でB

まずAします。それからB・準備としてまず～してから、その後で次に続く行動をする

Where it is necessary to do A first before doing B, A has significance
for what happens to B
```

When asking someone else, a sentence was given to me that is natural

お話は食事をした**上で**お聞きします

If this sentence is correct, why is a. wrong, what is the difference?

Comment: I feel like the answer is in your post. The explanation includes "まずAします". Do either option a or b in the question involve the person performing an action the way that c does?

Comment: @Leebo Here's my understanding of a. まず食事をします。それから薬を読んでください。This is stressing the importance of having the medicine after eating the food so I don't see what's wrong there. For b. I suspect it's wrong because the the person doing A and B are different. A (説明する) is the doctor, and B (薬を飲む) is the patient. But I'm not 100% sure about this.

Comment: It doesn't say 食事をした though... If it did, the subject of the first half and second half would be the same, but they're not.

Comment: @Leebo So basically, 上で requires the subject of both halves to be the same? In the case of a. the subject of the first clause is 食事（が終わる）, and the second clause is 薬（は飲む）. Would this be natural then? この薬は、食事をした上でお飲みください since both subjects are the same.

Comment: I think a is wrong due to the の上 being more about stressing need to do something as a preparation, than stressing sequence [and, as there is anyway the 食後 phrase]. As to why b is wrong, maybe it is about stressing that you need to act, and if there was an option  "d. 医師からの説明を十分理解した" I think that would also be correct.

Comment: As for "お話は食事をした上でお聞きします" I don't know if it is correct, but if it is, I would interpret so that a person is telling another one that "I will only listen to what you want to say after you have had a proper meal" [Indicating that the person who wants to speak, while he/she has something to say, is not "OK" and needs to get some nutrition to get him/her into a shape where he/she can properly   express his/her thoughts].

Comment: @Tuomo Perhaps that's what I'm most confused by, what counts as "preparation". As in the case above, my mind somehow interpreted it as: "In preparation for drinking the medicine, must eat food first", how does this differ from c? "In preparation for drinking the medicine, read instructions first"

Comment: @shade549 Sorry, I am not an English native [But, not Japanese either]. Maybe instead of "preparation", "prerequisite" would have been more appropriate. I think the ...た上 is more like "It is important that you have completed task X before doing Y, [and before encountering on Y you should make sure you also realize why X is a prerequisite for Y]" Taking after the meal is obviously  not about having had a meal 10 hours before, but about taking the medicine immediately after the meal.